# In JSON-LD, do node types have any effect on transformations?

Tags: json-ld

I've been playing around with json-ld for a bit now and I'm having a hard time understanding the point of node types (`@type` inside a regular node). It seems like their only purpose is is just give your node a type. This would allow a generic consumer to do something particular with your node depending on its type. They don't seem to affect anything else tho.

Do node types have any effect on transformation operations like expanding and compacting?

Comment: Why do you think that they should affect anything else? -- What exactly do you mean with effect on transformation? I mean, type IRIs/terms may also be expaneded/compacted, but this is not what you mean, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no, `@type` has no effect on JSON-LD transformations.  Transformations are just about different tree representation of the same data graph.  The purpose of declaring a `@type` for a node is primarily semantic -- e.g. it gives you a way to indicate that "the thing which has properties "name" and "email" and "affiliation" is a "Person".

As you say, this also means a consumer can perform a particular task depending on that type. Doing so might still make use of transformations: For instance, I might write some script that chooses to apply a JSON-LD framing transformation to extract "name" and "email" whenever I come across nodes of `@type` Person.  Without `@type` information, there would be no obvious way to write this to avoid picking up names or emails of other Types, (e.g. of Organizations, etc).  Note that this example exploits the fact that because we have a shared notion of what a `"@type:" "Person"` object is, we can anticipate that it might have properties such as `name` and `email`.